# Is it advisable to update google meta tags dynamically? Does google update meta tags like description and title if it is update via an ajax request?

Tags: jquery, seo, meta-tags, meta

I am not using Angular or any js framework. 
Only updating title and description after the ajax request is fired with the dynamic information.
I can see that after 2-3 weeks, few of my pages have this dynamic content but NOT ALL the pages have the updated dynamic meta tags in the google index.
How can this be done so that google indexes it properly for all the pages?

I am updating the same in the following way:

**Before:**

```
<meta name=”description” content=”Description coming from server.”>
```

**After the ajax request is performed:**

```
  $('meta[name=description]').attr('content','Dynamic Description after ajax success.');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a way to optimize your SEO ranking, however you have to leave the description for enouph time and NOT change it too much so that will be none-sense change with none effective results, i think it will be fine between 3 days and two weeks... that depends on other SEO contents, links, titles,..etc on the page.

and i am not getting the part of ajax, and why the syntax or programming language you use should take effect, i think there is no problem to change it with ajax or directly with PHP/ASP...

Comment: I wanted to know, Does google index dynamically updated meta tags after the page is loaded?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, however you can add the page by your self ;-) , use this link https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1

Comment: Thanks. I am aware about manual submitting :) Just wanted to know if google indexes dynamically generated content. 
Lets say if I hit a ajax request after 10 seconds of page load. Will this data be indexed by google? 
And if yes, then is it advisable to do so ?

Comment: No it won't be indexed directly at will take a couple of days, but it is pretty good technique...

Comment: Anyways. Found my solution. Google update's meta tags on page which are dynamically updated too. 
Cheers(Y)

Comment: yes sure, google updates dynamically meta tags like "description" and "robots", but not for old ones like "Keywords", however this update doesn't take effect directly and this what i was trying to tell you that it will take some time to take effect in your pages ranking, and this time is about 4-5 days..good luck